# C# Azure storage from one blob copy file to another blob

Tags: azure, download, upload, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

How can I read a file to stream from one blob and upload to another blob? My requirement is to copy a file from one blob to another blob with different file name? In C#

Comment: have you tested the code?

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way to achieve it is using ["**Azure Storage Data Movement Library**"](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-storage-data-movement-library-preview-2/) (you can get it thru nuget package).

This is a simple-sample to make the transfer:

```cs
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement;
using System;

namespace BlobClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=juanktest;AccountKey=loHQwke4lSEu1p2W3gg==";
            const string container1 = "juankcontainer";
            const string sourceBlobName = "test.txt";
            const string destBlobName = "newTest.txt";


            //Setup Account, blobclient and blobs
            CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(container1);
            blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();

            CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(sourceBlobName);

            CloudBlockBlob destinationBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(destBlobName);

            //Setup data transfer
            TransferContext context = new TransferContext();
            Progress<TransferProgress> progress = new Progress<TransferProgress>(
                (transferProgress) => {
                        Console.WriteLine("Bytes uploaded: {0}", transferProgress.BytesTransferred);
                });

            context.ProgressHandler = progress;

            // Start the transfer
            try
            {
                TransferManager.CopyAsync(sourceBlob, destinationBlob, 
                    false /* isServiceCopy */, 
                    null /* options */, context);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The transfer is cancelled: {0}", e.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("CloudBlob {0} is copied to {1} ====successfully====", 
                            sourceBlob.Uri.ToString(), 
                            destinationBlob.Uri.ToString());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that "**Azure Storage Data Movement Library**" is very robust so you can track the transfer progress,  cancel the operation or even suspend it to resume it later ;)

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways to copy files is with the [AzCopy](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy) utility.

Answer (score 0):

- I would like to recommend another method other than the above to get this done.
- That is **azure functions.** (serverless compute service).
- As a prerequisite, you should have some knowledge in azure functions, creating them, deploying them. 1. [What is azure function](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-functions/#:%7E:text=Azure%20Functions%20allows%20developers%20to,applications%2C%20mobile%20and%20IoT%20devices.) 2. [create an Azure function app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function)
- And the following code snippet is the simplest and basic way to perform this action. (In here, when a user uploading a new file to the "demo" blob, the function will be triggered and read that uploaded file from the demo blob and copy to the "output" blob.)

  ```
   namespace Company.Function{
   public static class NamalFirstBlobTrigger
   {
       [FunctionName("NamalFirstBlobTrigger")]
       public static void Run([BlobTrigger("demo/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, 
       [Blob("output/testing.cs",FileAccess.Write, Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream outputBlob,
       string name, 
       ILogger log)
       {
           myBlob.CopyTo(outputBlob);
       }
   }}
  ```